# Count how many cells have a number greater than zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have K2, T2, AC2, AL2, and AV2 with numbers in them.  I want to count how many of those are greater than zero.  For instance, K2 is 4, T2 is 17, AC2 is 0, AL2 is 3, and AV2 is 6.  I would expect an answer of 4, because 4 out of 5 cells is greater than zero.  I have tried multiple formulas, all returning errors.  So if I use countif, and my range is the cells K2, T2, AC2, AL2, and AV2 and my criteria is >0 I get an error.  Help please?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following formula.

```
=(K2>0)+(T2>0)+(AC2>0)+(AL2>0)+(AV2>0)
```

Comment: Very interesting use of an inherent true/false test!

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty:

```
=SUM(IF(K2>0,1),IF(T2>0,1),IF(AC2>0,1),IF(AL2>0,1),IF(AV2>0,1))
```